# How to create a wifi hotspot using tails or whonix?

Tags: configuration, tails, network-configuration, whonix

NetworkManager in ubuntu and arch have a handy feature that allows users to turn an additional wireless card into a wifi hotspot. The idea is: boot whonix or tails in virtualbox, connect a wireless adapter to the vm, configure the wireless adapter to act as a hotspot.

Looking at the Tails wifi manager, I couldn't figure out how to create a wireless AP. I imagine that option was removed for security reasons. The Whonix wifi manager has a feature to create a wireless AP but it doesnt seem to work.

Can anyone assist?

NOTE: I understand the risks of using a torified wireless AP. Wireless crypto sucks. This is merely a proof of concept/experiment.

Comment: It's [unsupported](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Unsupported).

"I imagine that option was removed for security reasons." - No settings related to that were changed in Whonix.

The gateway has transparent proxying disabled by default. You could try this inside a Whonix-Workstation. Could even work.

Comment: I'm trying to use my internet wired connection on tails as a hostpot for other devices of mine and actually I see no way to do that. The idea is to make all connections to the internet on my other devices that do not support tails occur through Tor. Is that what you're trying to do so? Have you found any way?

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Dev/Torified_Wi-Fi_Hotspot